# How can I optimize a search over two sets of files to merge them?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I've got a bunch of .txt files with alphabetically-sorted file names:

```
aaa.txt
aab.txt
aac.txt
.
.
.
zzz.txt
```

And another set of .txt files stored in a different location:

```
ant.txt
bat.txt
cat.txt
lion.txt
...
```

I want to take the text of .txt files in the latter group and append them to the appropriate file in the first group. (There is a chance that a file in the second group does not exist in the first group.)
For example, I want to take the contents of `ant.txt` from the second group and append that to `ant.txt` in the first group.

How can I do this efficiently?
The obvious way is:

```
for file in second group:
   for file in first group:
      # check if the names are identical; if they are, append
```

But this seems really inefficient. A human trying to find `cat.txt` in the first group wouldn't start searching from aaa.txt, they'd immediately jump to the files that start with ca.

I imagine one way to optimize this is to remove `cat.txt` from the search once it's been updated, possibly by storing the updated file in a third directory, and deleting `cat.txt` from the first group(?)

If it matters, I'm using Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.listdir` along with `os.path.isfile` to find the files you are interested in.

Then use `open(filename, 'r')` to read the content of a file and `open(filename, 'a')` to append to the end of a file.

```py
import os
import sys

def append_second_group_to_first_group(target_folder_path, source_folder_path):
    for filename in os.listdir(source_folder_path):
        source_file_path = os.path.join(source_folder_path, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(source_file_path):
            target_file_path = os.path.join(target_folder_path, filename)
            if os.path.isfile(target_file_path):
                with open(target_file_path, 'a') as out_f:
                    with open(source_file_path, 'r') as in_f:
                        out_f.writelines(in_f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    target, source = sys.argv[1:3]
    append_second_group_to_first_group(target, source)
```

Testing with two folders `1/` and `2/` containing a few text files:

##### Before

```
$ for f in 1/*; do     echo $f; cat $f; echo; done
1/aaa.txt
aaa

1/ant.txt
ant

1/bbb.txt
bbb

1/cat.txt
cat

$ for f in 2/*; do     echo $f; cat $f; echo; done
2/ant.txt
Ants are so cool

2/bat.txt
Bats fly under the radar

2/cat.txt
Cats are sleeping in my armchair
```

##### After

```
$ python3 appendfiles.py 1 2
$ for f in 1/*; do     echo $f; cat $f; echo; done
1/aaa.txt
aaa

1/ant.txt
ant
Ants are so cool

1/bbb.txt
bbb

1/cat.txt
cat
Cats are sleeping in my armchair
```

Note how the content of the `bat.txt` file was not copied, because there is no `bat.txt` file in folder `1/`. It's unclear in the current wording of your question whether you want `bat.txt` to be copied or not in this situation. If you do want `bat.txt` to be copied, then simply remove line `if os.path.isfile(target_file_path):` from the code above.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment say you can use set to achieve that :

Setup your list.

```
list1 = ["aaa","ant","bbb","cat"]
list2 = ["cat","ant","lion"]
```

Convert the lists to sets and find the intersection

```
common_elements = set(list1) & set(list2)
```

Here you go you get your correspondance

```
print(output)  # Output: {'ant', 'cat'}
```

Comment: op has files and not strings

Comment: I explain him how to get identical name from two list. The input in the list is up to him.

Comment: This is still incorrect. OP needs to append two files into one. ie append the contents of the 2nd file to the first file if the files have the same name. Please read through the question again